# Why isn't the text in my react-native SearchBar updating?

Tags: javascript, react-native, searchbar

When I type, nothing shows up in the search bar, but it knows that I'm typing (from the print statements in my updateSearch function). From my understanding of the react-native searchBar, there isn't even anything I need to do for text to be showing up there, so I really have no idea how I could have screwed this up. This is a part of a larger project.. but I'm praying this issue doesn't have anything to do with the rest of it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import { SearchBar, List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class Search extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      query: "",
      data: []
    };

  }

  renderHeader = () => {
    return (
    <SearchBar
    placeholder="Type Here..."
    onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
    lightTheme={true}
    />
    );
  }

  updateSearch = text => {
    console.log("text", text);
    const formattedSearch = text.toLowerCase();
    this.setState({ query: formattedSearch });
    console.log("text", this.state.query);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Header text={"Search"} />
        <FlatList
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So in your search bar can you add the value props and check.

```
renderHeader = () => {
    return (
    <SearchBar
    placeholder="Type Here..."
    onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
    lightTheme={true}
    value={this.state.query}
    />
    );
  }
```

So i believe you are storing your search text in state as query varibale. So value is this.state.query.

Hope it helps. Ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: I had tried that to no avail, should have included it in the version of the code i posted, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Make your `<SearchBar/>` component a Controlled Input/Controlled Component by updating the value when the `onChangeText` event is fired.

```
<SearchBar
    placeholder="Type Here..."
    onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
    value={this.state.query}
    lightTheme={true}
/>
```

Doing it this way - updating the state for each new character might concern you from a performance standpoint, but it's the offical way that React recomends that you do it. Controlled Inputs like this are very common.

Comment: I had tried that to no avail, should have included it in the version of the code i posted, my bad